# Why when apply Map.prototype.forEach will return undefined?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, undefined

[image]

I try to study the Map object by reading document. However, it confuses me in the beginning. I wonder what does it mean by" Return undefined." here?

Comment: Can you link the document you are reading, please?

Comment: It should be "Return*s* `undefined`", or "Does return `undefined`", and it just means that the return value of the call is `undefined`.

Comment: It might be helpful to check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach).

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder what does it mean by" Return undefined." here?

It means the function `forEach` will execute the provided function `f` and nothing else, basically, the function `forEach` doesn't return anything because its job is to loop the provided entries calling the callback function `f` on every entry within the map.

If the callback returns a value, this will be ignored.

```js
var undefinedValue = new Map([
  ['foo', 3],
  ['bar', {}],
  ['baz', 2]
]).forEach(() => {
  console.log('Looping...');
  return "HELLO WORLD!"; // This will be ignored!
});

console.log("Value returned from forEach:", undefinedValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

This just means that the effect of `forEach` is entirely dependent on what you do inside the function `f`, you don't get an overall returned value from the `forEach` operation. If you did this:

```
let a = arr.forEach(myFunc);
```

...then `a` would be undefined.